# Easier attendance method to Skype for Business meetings?

Tags: skype-for-business

Our organisation uses the native desktop Skype for Business 2016 client.

When I want to have meetings with external users I send them the standard Outlook invitation created by the S4B add-in.

This works fine for most users, but for some external clients they are restricted by security policies and are unable to download the MSI plug-in required for web meetings.

Is there a way round this?  Is it possible to host a Skype meeting and invite external users with the minimum fuss?

I came across [this page](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Join-a-Skype-for-Business-meeting-with-Skype-Meetings-App-Skype-for-Business-Web-App-4828ad18-ed21-422a-a870-94d676d4b72a) which may be relevant?

Comment: This site is for personal computer and home networking issues. It doesn't sound like you have a problem with your computer or software. The problem is the corporate policies of the external users you want to connect with. I don't see how we are going to be able to help you with that. Those users are affected by something you have no control over.

Comment: You would need to check with your IT. You might either be able to setup a federation with your client, in which case you would be able to use the skype client directly, or you might be able to offer a call-in method. There is no pure "HTML" based solution (currently).